# Menu Bootstrap, incluir logotipo

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-3

Galera, estou usando esse menu: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/ Exatamente esse do link, copiei diretamente daí, a questão é, onde está escrito "Project Name", tenho que adicionar um um logotipo, como faço?

Comment: já conseguiu resolver ?

Answer (score 3):

Na parte que esta assim:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
```

Altera para:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="../images/suaImagem.png" width="45px" height="28px"></a>
```

Onde o width e o height são largura e altura da imagem respectivamente

Comment: Só adicionando o link na documentação, caso o op queira: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-brand-image